# Jupyter Lab not executing K-Fold Cross Validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, jupyter, cross-validation

I am using 5 cross validation and the F1 metric to evaluate my Neural Network.

However, when running my code in Jupyter Labs, it seems to load forever. Not producing any output, but running other tasks is fine.

I have a total of 5 folds, and 500 epochs.
Every 50 epochs, I output the Mean Squared Error loss value (x10 per fold). After 500 epochs (1 fold), I output the current F1 value of whatever test set I give it.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn import metrics

lr = 0.01
cross_val_score(lr,x_train,y_train,cv=5,scoring='mean_squared_error')

f1s = [] # to capture F1 score for every Fold
kf = KFold(n_splits=5)
for train, test in kf.split(x):
    for epoch in range(500):
        ridge.fit(x[train], y[train])
        if epoch % 50 == 0:  # prints MSE 10 times over each fold
            print(mean_squared_error(y[test], ridge.predict(x[test])))
            print("MSE: " + metrics.mean_squared_error(predictions, y))
    f1 = metrics.f1_score(predictions, y) # appends each fold
    f1s.append(f1)
    print("F1: " + f1)

print("Average F1: " + np.mean(macro_f1))
```

Note: fold and epoch values are low due to my low computer spec. I am using Jupyter Labs.

What am I doing wrong that makes this run perpetually?

Comment: whats your `x`?

Comment: x and y come from return_X_y (which I made lower case). I've not included this as I want to have this work across other neural nets I have in mind.

Comment: You seem to have made some errors in trying to produce a minimal example: `predictions` isn't defined, nor is `macro_f1`, and `cross_val_score` should take a model as its first argument.  Without sample data, we can only guess.  What happens if you try to print after the first epoch (i.e., does the very first fit succeed)?  Does `ridge.fit` actually _continue_ training, or is it refitting?